# How would I increment or otherwise change a value in a record with "Simon-ness"

Tags: haskell

The below code is from this [tutorial](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/)

it illustrates very well how to operate on values from records with "Simon-ness" (illustrated below). What I am struggling with is how to modify values inside records with "Simon-ness", say incrementing "age". I keep thinking it has to do with the way Label is defined with the constructor Get. Could I add another constructor Put?

> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
>
>
> import GHC.TypeLits
>
> newtype Field (n :: Symbol) v = Field { unField :: v } deriving Show
>
> data Person1 = Person1
>   { _age      :: Field "age" Int
>   , _name     :: Field "name" String
>   }
>
> data Person2 = Person2
>   { _age'  :: Field "age" Int
>   , _name' :: Field "name" String
>   , _lib'  :: Field "lib" String
>   }
>
> deriving instance Show Person1
> deriving instance Show Person2
>
> data Label (l :: Symbol) = Get
>
> class Has a l b | a l -> b where
>   from :: a -> Label l -> b
>
> instance Has Person1 "age" Int where
>   from (Person1 a _) _ = unField a
>
> instance Has Person1 "name" String where
>   from (Person1 _ a) _ = unField a
>
> instance Has Person2 "age" Int where
>   from (Person2 a _ _) _ = unField a
>
> instance Has Person2 "name" String where
>   from (Person2 _ a _) _ = unField a
>
> age :: Has a "age" b => a -> b
> age pnt = from pnt (Get :: Label "age")
>
> name :: Has a "name" b => a -> b
> name pnt = from pnt (Get :: Label "name")
>
> -- Parameterized constraint kind for "Simon-ness" of a record.
> type Simon a = (Has a "name" String, Has a "age" Int)
>
> spj :: Person1
> spj = Person1 (Field 56) (Field "Simon Peyton Jones")
>
> smarlow :: Person2
> smarlow = Person2 (Field 38) (Field "Simon Marlow") (Field "rts")
>
>
> catNames :: (Simon a, Simon b) => a -> b -> String
> catNames a b = name a ++ name b
>
> addAges :: (Simon a, Simon b) => a -> b -> Int
> addAges a b = age a + age b
>
>
> names :: String
> names = name smarlow ++ "," ++ name spj
> -- "Simon Marlow,Simon Peyton Jones"
>
> ages :: Int
> ages = age spj + age smarlow
> -- 94
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shooting from the hip here...

There class `Has` is not powerful enough to set values. You would have to add another typeclass function, e.g. something like:

```
class Has a l b | a l -> b where
  from :: a -> Label l -> b
  set  :: b -> a -> Label l -> a
```

and the definitions for `Person1` might go like this:

```
instance Has Person1 "age" Int where
  from (Person1 a _) _ = unField a
  set v (Person1 a b) _ = Person1 (Field v) b
```

and an `incAge` function could be written like this:

```
incAge :: (Num b, Has a "age" b) => a -> a
incAge pnt = let a = from pnt (Get :: Label "age")
             in set (a+1) pnt (Get :: Label "age")
```

This compiles, although I'm not sure if this is really useful or the best approach.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I will apply it to my project, and present to the community. Then we can talk about better approaches.

Comment: There was a comment from another person here. I think I removed it by accident. How to restore?